# Flex layout with grid system in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have created a flex layout bellow:

```
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
    <div class="bg-gray-400 h-12 flex-shrink-0 header">Header</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-300 flex-grow content">Content</div>
    <div class="bg-gray-400 h-12 flex-shrink-0 footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
```

Now I want to achieve same thing with grid. What I tried is bellow.

```
<div class="min-h-screen grid grid-rows-3">
  <div class="bg-gray-400 h-12 header">Header</div>
  <div class="bg-gray-300 content">Content</div>
  <div class="bg-gray-400 h-12 footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

But this does not give me what I expected. Any help ?
I expect it to be

[image]

Comment: Rather than `grid-rows-3` you will want the css to be `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will works:

```html
<div class="min-h-screen grid grid-rows-[48px,1fr,48px]">
  <div class="bg-gray-400 h-12 header">Header</div>
  <div class="bg-gray-300 content">Content</div>
  <div class="bg-gray-400 footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also `grid-rows-[auto,1fr,auto]` 
https://play.tailwindcss.com/RW2PNezI24